# Бот перестал отвечать на соообщения,что делать?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Такая проблема,попытался добавить калькулятор кв. уравнений, терминал ошибки не видит,но сам бот в тг не отвечает, в чем проблема? В расположении хэндлеров? Кидаю два кусочка кода(в питоне не сильно силен).

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
import time
import math
from urllib.request import urlopen
import sqlite3
from pymongo import MongoClient



# Создаем экземпляр бота
bot = telebot.TeleBot('5444586254:AAHYDxQGU94cGXqZYDo1vAP51CMyBQUwtws')
# Функция, обрабатывающая команду /start

cur_state = None

cluster = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://palladium:rinigu77@cluster0.fzugi.mongodb.net/mathbot?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
db = cluster["mathbot"]
user = db["users"]


def Handler_SquareRoot(message: types.Message):
    global cur_state
    a, b, c = [int(num) for num in message.text.split(' ')]

    D = b * b - 4 * a * c
    if D < 0:
        mess = "Дискриминант меньше нуля, корней нет"
    elif D == 0:
        x = -b / (2 * a)
        mess = f"Дискриминант равен нулю, единственный корень:\nx = {x:.5f}"
    else:
        x1 = (-b + math.sqrt(D)) / (2 * a)
        x2 = (-b - math.sqrt(D)) / (2 * a)
        mess = f"Дискриминант больше нуля, корни:\nx1 = {x1:.5f}, x2 = {x2:.5f}"

    cur_state = None
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess)


# States
state_SquareRootGet = "SquareRootGet"
state_handlers = {
    state_SquareRootGet: Handler_SquareRoot
}

already_added = False


# Функция, обрабатывающая команду /start
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"], chat_types=['private'])
def start(message: types.Message):
    if user.find_one({"user_id": message.from_user.id}):
        return
    else:
        user.insert_one({"user_id": message.from_user.id, "user_name": f"{message.from_user.username}"})

    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
    markup.add('Начать поиск:', 'Связь с разработчиком', 'Поддержать разработку',
               'Список сокращений:', 'Быстрый поиск:', 'Калькулятор кв. уравнений')
    bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id,
                     text=f'Привет, {message.from_user.first_name}!\n'
                          f'Я формулознайка, наилучший бот - помощник в поиске формул по математике , '
                          f'выбери что ты хочешь:',
                     # parse_mode='html',
                     reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(commands=["checkuser"], func=lambda msg: msg.from_user.id == 1219000385)
def check_user(message: types.Message):
    users = user.find({})
    coutn_users = user.count_documents({})
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Кол-во пользователей, которые используют Ваш бот: {coutn_users}")
    for user_ in users:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"ID = {user_['user_id']}\nUsername = @{user_['user_name']}")


# во-первых делайте для каждого вашего if одтельный хендлер
# не и всякие content_types=["text"] который стоят по-умолчанию смысла писать нет
# также рекомендую указывть аннотации, они облегчат написание кода
# к примеру message: types.Message, если вы юзате pycharm
# то он будет давать подсказки если вы напишете message. (с точкой)
# вместо ваших ифов делаете такую конструкцию, вы будете смотреть на хендлер
# и сразу поймете что он делает и при каких условиях срабатывает
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda msg: msg.text == "Калькулятор кв. уравнений")
def func(message: types.Message):
    global cur_state
    # даже pycharm ругается на эту запись
    # if not cur_state is None:
    # делайте так. Так даже понятнее, типа такой-то стейт является не None
    if cur_state is not None:
        state_handlers[cur_state](message)
        print("Changed state to ", cur_state)
    else:
        # зачем вы создаете переменную mess? Оно же только мешает восприятию
        # mess = "Введи a, b, c из a*x*x + b*x + c = 0"
        # просто сделайте перенос строки
        bot.send_message(
            chat_id=message.chat.id,
            text="Введи a, b, c из a*x*x + b*x + c = 0",
            # зачем вам указывать parse_mode? Вы же не пользуетесь им.
            # parse_mode='html',
            reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())
        cur_state = state_SquareRootGet
        print("Changed state to ", cur_state)


# здесь у вас была просто функция без декоратора, потому бот не видел её
# я разбил её на два хендлера
# ах и ещё вместо ифа if message.chat.type == 'private'
# я сделал это условия в самом хендлере
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda msg: msg.text == 'Поддержать разработку', chat_types=["private"])
def support(message: types.Message):
    bot.send_message(
        chat_id=message.chat.id,
        text='Поддержите разработку если считаете это нужным, это поможет проэкту существовать и развиваться '
             'Карта ПриватБанка: 5168 7559 0884 1170 Спасибо заранее!')


@bot.message_handler(chat_types=['private'], func=lambda msg: msg.text == 'Быстрый поиск:')
def fast_search(message: types.Message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
    markup.add('Алгебра', 'Геометрия♾️', 'Вернуться в главное меню⬅️')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выбери предмет:', reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(chat_types=['private'], func=lambda msg: msg.text == 'Геометрия♾️')
def geometry(message: types.Message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
    markup.add('Квадрат', 'Прямоугольник⬜', 'Круг',
               'Треугольник', 'Ромб', 'Трапеция⏢', 'Вернуться в быстрый выбор⬅️')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выбери фигуру:', reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(chat_types=['private'], func=lambda msg: msg.text == 'Вернуться в быстрый выбор⬅️')
def back_to_fast_search(message: types.Message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
    markup.add('Алгебра', 'Геометрия♾️', 'Вернуться в главное меню⬅️')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     f'Ты в быстром поиске,{message.from_user.first_name}! Выбери что ты хочешь:',
                     reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(chat_types=['private'], func=lambda msg: msg.text == 'Алгебра')
def algebra(message: types.Message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
    markup.add('Вернуться назад⬅️', 'Таблица умножения', 'Квадратное уравнение', 'Графики')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     'Ты в разделе Алгебра, выбери что ты хочешь:',
                     reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(chat_types=['private'], func=lambda msg: msg.text == 'Вернуться назад⬅️')
def back(message: types.Message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
    markup.add('Алгебра', 'Геометрия♾️', 'Вернуться в главное меню⬅️')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     f'Ты в быстром поиске,{message.from_user.first_name}! Выбери что ты хочешь:',
                     reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(chat_types=['private'], func=lambda msg: msg.text == 'Вернуться в главное меню⬅️')
def back_to_main_menu(message: types.Message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
    markup.add('Начать поиск', 'Связь с разработчиком', 'Поддержать разработку',
               'Список сокращений', 'Быстрый поиск', 'Калькулятор кв. уравнений')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     f'Ты в главном меню,{message.from_user.first_name}! Выбери что ты хочешь:',
                     reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(chat_types=['private'], func=lambda msg: msg.text == 'Графики')
def graphic(message: types.Message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    markup.add('Линейная', 'Квадратическая', 'Степенная', 'Обратно-пропорциональная', 'Логарифмическая',
               'Функция в модуле', 'Другие функции(sin,cos)', 'Вернуться назад⬅️')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     f'Ты в поиске графиков,{message.from_user.first_name}! Выбери какой график тебе нужен:',
                     reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(chat_types=['private'], func=lambda msg: msg.text == 'Другие функции(sin,cos)')
def other_funcs(message: types.Message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    markup.add('sin', 'cos', 'tg', 'ctg', 'Вернуться назад⬅️')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     f'Ты в поиске графиков,{message.from_user.first_name}! Выбери какой график тебе нужен:',
                     reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(chat_types=['private'], func=lambda msg: msg.text == 'Список сокращений')
def list_abbreviations(message: types.Message):
    bot.send_message(
        message.chat.id,
        'Треуг.(Тр.)➡️Треугольник\nКв.➡️Квадрат\nПрямоуг.➡️Прямоугольник(-ый)\nОкр.➡️Окружность(круг)\n'
        'Впис.➡️Вписанный\nОпис.➡️Описанный\nПрил.➡️Прилежащая\nРавноб.➡️Равнобедренный\nКат.➡️Катет\n'
        'Гипот.➡️Гипотенуза\nСтор.➡️Стороны\nИзв.➡️Изввестный(-ая)\nH(h)➡️Высота в общей геометрии\n'
        'S(s)➡️Площадь в общей геометрии\nL➡️Сторона в общей геометрии\nM(m)➡️Медиана в общей геометрии\n'
        'Произв.➡️Произвольный(ого)\nПолуп.➡️Полупериметр\nОсн.➡️Основние/основа\nЧ/з➡️Через\nР-но➡️Ровно\n'
        'Равтост.➡️Равносторонний')


@bot.message_handler(chat_types=['private'], func=lambda msg: msg.text == 'Связь с разработчиком')
def contact(message: types.Message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Связь с разработчиком: @MarcoPopa')


@bot.message_handler(chat_types=['private'], func=lambda msg: msg.text == 'Начать поиск')
def start_search(message: types.Message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'P.s после каждого ответа бота можете сразу продолжать искать другие формулы. '
                                      'Введи название формулы  ниже')


@bot.message_handler(chat_types=['private'], func=lambda msg: msg.text in [
    'Таблица умножения', 'Табличка умножения', 'таблица умножения', 'табличка множения'])
def multiplication_table(message: types.Message):
    photo1 = open('png/3ebc0dfa867e344cf30d81409cfd7558.jpg', 'rb')
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo1)


@bot.message_handler(chat_types=['private'], func=lambda msg: msg.text in [
    'теорема пифагора', 'Теорема Пифагора', 'теорема Пифагора'])
def pythagoras_theorem(message: types.Message):
    photo1 = open('png/maxresdefault.jpg', 'rb')
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.infinity_polling(skip_pending=True)


elif message.text =='Список сокращений:':
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess2)
elif message.text == 'Связь с разработчиком':
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess3)
elif message.text == 'Начать поиск:':
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess4)
elif message.text in ['Таблица умножения', 'Табличка умножения','таблица умножения','табличка множения']:
    photo1 = open('png/3ebc0dfa867e344cf30d81409cfd7558.jpg', 'rb')
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo1)
elif message.text in ['теорема пифагора','Теорема Пифагора','теорема Пифагора']:
    photo1 = open('png/maxresdefault.jpg', 'rb')
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo1)
elif message.text == 'свойства степени':
    photo1 = open('png/shk-1355-osnovnyie-svojstva-stepenej-kornej-1x1.png', 'rb')
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo1)
elif message.text == 'степень':
    photo1 = open('png/shk-1355-osnovnyie-svojstva-stepenej-kornej-1x1.png', 'rb')
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo1)
elif message.text == 'свойства степеней':
    photo1 = open('png/shk-1355-osnovnyie-svojstva-stepenej-kornej-1x1.png', 'rb')
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo1)
elif message.text == 'преобразование степеней':
    photo1 = open('png/shk-1355-osnovnyie-svojstva-stepenej-kornej-1x1.png', 'rb')
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo1)
elif message.text == 'свойства корней':
    photo1 = open('png/img_user_file_5da7f96abe2fa_5.jpg', 'rb')
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo1)
elif message.text == 'корневые свойства':
    photo1 = open('png/img_user_file_5da7f96abe2fa_5.jpg', 'rb')
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo1)
elif message.text == 'основные свойства корней':
    photo1 = open('png/img_user_file_5da7f96abe2fa_5.jpg', 'rb')
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo1)
elif message.text == 'многочлен':
    photo2 = open('png/ggvp1.jpg','rb')
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo2)
elif message.text == 'теорема Безу':
    photo1 = open('png/slide-7.jpg', 'rb')
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo1)
elif message.text == 'Безу':
    photo1 = open('png/slide-7.jpg', 'rb')
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo1)
elif message.text == 'теорема безу':
    photo1 = open('png/slide-7.jpg', 'rb')
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo1)
elif message.text == 'Квадратное уравнение':
    mess8 = '''Квадратное уравнение — это уравнение вида ax2 + bx + c = 0, где a — первый или старший коэффициент, не равный нулю, b — второй коэффициент, c — свободный член. Дискриминант квадратного уравнения — это выражение, равное b2 − 4ac.\nДискриминант в переводе с латинского означает «отличающий» или «различающий» и обозначается буквой D.'''
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess8)
    bot.send_media_group(message.chat.id, [telebot.types.InputMediaPhoto(open('png/дискриминант.jpg', 'rb')), telebot.types.InputMediaPhoto(open('png/slide-17.jpg', 'rb')) ])
elif message.text == 'дискриминант':
    mess8 = '''Квадратное уравнение — это уравнение вида ax2 + bx + c = 0, где a — первый или старший коэффициент, не равный нулю, b — второй коэффициент, c — свободный член. Дискриминант квадратного уравнения — это выражение, равное b2 − 4ac.\nДискриминант в переводе с латинского означает «отличающий» или «различающий» и обозначается буквой D.'''
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess8)
    bot.send_media_group(message.chat.id, [telebot.types.InputMediaPhoto(open('png/дискриминант.jpg', 'rb')), telebot.types.InputMediaPhoto(open('png/slide-17.jpg', 'rb')) ])
elif message.text == 'квадратное уравнение':
    mess8 = '''Квадратное уравнение — это уравнение вида ax2 + bx + c = 0, где a — первый или старший коэффициент, не равный нулю, b — второй коэффициент, c — свободный член. Дискриминант квадратного уравнения — это выражение, равное b2 − 4ac.\nДискриминант в переводе с латинского означает «отличающий» или «различающий» и обозначается буквой D.'''
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess8)
    bot.send_media_group(message.chat.id, [telebot.types.InputMediaPhoto(open('png/дискриминант.jpg', 'rb')), telebot.types.InputMediaPhoto(open('png/slide-17.jpg', 'rb')) ])
elif message.text.lower() == 'таблица степеней':
    photo1 = open('png/table-degrees-1-1.png', 'rb')
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo1)
elif message.text.lower() == 'степенная таблица':
    photo1 = open('png/table-degrees-1-1.png', 'rb')
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo1)
elif message.text.lower() in ['таблица производных', 'производные', 'свойства производной', 'свойства производных']:
    photo1 = open('png/proiz_2.gif', 'rb')
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo1)
elif message.text.lower() in ['функция в модуле', 'модульная функция','модульный график', 'функция в модуле']:
    mess9 = ('График функции y = |x| выглядит следующим образом:')
    photo1 = open('png/298.png', 'rb')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess9)
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo1)
elif message.text.lower() in ['гипербола', 'ветки гиперболы','обратно-пропорциональная зависимость','обратно-пропорциональный график', 'обратно пропорциональная зависимость', 'обратно-пропорциональная']:
    mess10 = 'Обратно пропорциональной зависимостью называют функцию, заданную формулой: y= k/x. В зависимости от знака числа k график обратно пропорциональной зависимости может иметь два принципиальных варианта:'
    photo1 = open('png/282.png', 'rb')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess10)
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo1)
elif message.text.lower() in ['график логарифма', 'логарифмическая функция','логарифм', 'логарифмическая']:
    photo1 = open('png/286.png', 'rb')
    mess11 = 'Логарифмической функцией называют функцию, заданную формулой: y = logX В зависимости от того больше или меньше единицы число a график логарифмической функции может иметь два принципиальных варианта:'
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess11)
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo1)
elif message.text.lower() in ['линейная функция', 'функция линии','график линии','линейный график', 'линейная']:
    mess12 = 'Линейная функция — это функция вида y = kx + b, где х — независимая переменная, k, b — некоторые числа'
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess12)
    photo1 = open('png/277.png', 'rb')
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo1)
elif message.text.lower() in ['квадратическая функция', 'график параболы','парабола','функция параболы', 'квадратическая']:
    mess = 'График параболы задается квадратичной функцией:x=y^2. Квадратичная функция, как и любая другая функция, пересекает ось ОХ в точках являющихся её корнями: (x1; 0) и (x2; 0). Если корней нет, значит квадратичная функция ось ОХ не пересекает, если корень один, значит в этой точке (x0; 0) квадратичная функция только касается оси ОХ, но не пересекает её. Квадратичная функция всегда пересекает ось OY в точке с координатами: (0; c). График квадратичной функции (парабола) может выглядеть следующим образом (на рисунке примеры, которые далеко не исчерпывают все возможные виды парабол):'
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess)
    photo1 = open('png/278.png', 'rb')
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo1)
elif message.text.lower() in ['степенная функция', 'функция степени','функция третьей степени','функция четвертой степени', 'степенная']:
    mess = 'Степенной функцией называют функцию, заданную формулой:Формула степенной функцииПриведем несколько примеров графиков степенных функций:'
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess)
    photo1 = open('png/280.png', 'rb')
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo1)
elif message.text.lower() in ['формулы сокращенного умножения', 'фсу','формула сокращенного умножения','сокращенное умножение']:
    mess = 'Формулы сокращенного умножения:'
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess)
    photo1 = open('png/fsu-1.png', 'rb')
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo1)
elif message.text.lower() in ['график синуса', 'синусоида','sin', 'периодическая функция']:
    mess = 'Большинство примеров периодических функций - это тригонометрические функции. Приведем графики основных тригонометрических функций. На следующем рисунке изображена часть графика функции y = sinx (весь график неограниченно продолжается влево и вправо), график функции y = sinx называют синусоидой:'
    photo1 = open('png/290.png', 'rb')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess)
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo1)

print('Бот запущен')
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: `def bot_message(message): ` Я так понимаю эта часть кода не работает?

Comment: да,не пойму почему,все стальное ок,реагирует только на  Калькулятор кв. уравнений

Comment: переделал код,не реагирует на старт

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас есть вот этот код.

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def func(message):
    global cur_state

    if not cur_state is None:
        state_handlers[cur_state](message)
        print("Changed state to ", cur_state)
    else:
        if(message.text == "Калькулятор кв. уравнений"):
            mess = "Введи a, b, c из a*x*x + b*x + c = 0"
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess, parse_mode='html', reply_markup=clear_markup)
            cur_state = state_SquareRootGet
            print("Changed state to ", cur_state)

def bot_message(message):
    mess2 = '''Треуг.(Тр.)➡️Треугольник\nКв.➡️Квадрат\nПрямоуг.➡️Прямоугольник(-ый)\nОкр.➡️Окружность(круг)\nВпис.➡️Вписанный\nОпис.➡️Описанный\nПрил.➡️Прилежащая\nРавноб.➡️Равнобедренный\nКат.➡️Катет\nГипот.➡️Гипотенуза\nСтор.➡️Стороны\nИзв.➡️Изввестный(-ая)\nH(h)➡️Высота в общей геометрии\nS(s)➡️Площадь в общей геометрии\nL➡️Сторона в общей геометрии\nM(m)➡️Медиана в общей геометрии\nПроизв.➡️Произвольный(ого)\nПолуп.➡️Полупериметр\nОсн.➡️Основние/основа\nЧ/з➡️Через\nР-но➡️Ровно\nРавтост.➡️Равносторонний'''
    mess1 = 'Поддержите разработку если считаете это нужным, это поможет проэкту существовать и развиваться Карта ПриватБанка: 5168 7559 0884 1170 Спасибо заранее!'
    mess3 = 'Связь с разработчиком: @MarcoPopa'
    mess4 = 'P.s после каждого ответа бота можете сразу продолжать искать другие формулы. Введи название формулы  ниже'
    mess5 = 'Введи ниже переменную а'
    mess6 = 'Введи переменную b'
    mess7 = 'Введи переменную с'

    if message.chat.type == 'private':

        if message.text == 'Поддержать разработку':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess1)

        if message.text =='Быстрый поиск:':
                markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True, row_width=2)
                algebra = types.KeyboardButton('Алгебра')
                geoma = types.KeyboardButton('Геометрия♾️')
                nazadbistr = types.KeyboardButton('Вернуться в главное меню⬅️')
                markup.add(algebra, geoma, nazadbistr)
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выбери предмет:', parse_mode = 'html', reply_markup = markup)
```

Это ужас. Немного потыкал, поменял на вот это

```
# во-первых делайте для каждого вашего if одтельный хендлер
# не и всякие content_types=["text"] который стоят по-умолчанию смысла писать нет
# также рекомендую указывть аннотации, они облегчат написание кода
# к примеру message: types.Message, если вы юзате pycharm
# то он будет давать подсказки если вы напишете message. (с точкой)
# вместо ваших ифов делаете такую конструкцию, вы будете смотреть на хендлер
# и сразу поймете что он делает и при каких условиях срабатывает 
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda msg: msg.text == "Калькулятор кв. уравнений")
def func(message: types.Message):
    global cur_state
    # даже pycharm ругается на эту запись
    # if not cur_state is None:
    # делайте так. Так даже понятнее, типа такой-то стейт является не None
    if cur_state is not None:
        state_handlers[cur_state](message)
        print("Changed state to ", cur_state)
    else:
        # зачем вы создаете переменную mess? Оно же только мешает восприятию
        # mess = "Введи a, b, c из a*x*x + b*x + c = 0"
        # просто сделайте перенос строки
        bot.send_message(
            chat_id=message.chat.id,
            text="Введи a, b, c из a*x*x + b*x + c = 0",
            # зачем вам указывать parse_mode? Вы же не пользуетесь им.
            # parse_mode='html', 
            reply_markup=clear_markup)
        cur_state = state_SquareRootGet
        print("Changed state to ", cur_state)


# здесь у вас была просто функция без декоратора, потому бот не видел её
# я разбил её на два хендлера
# ах и ещё вместо ифа if message.chat.type == 'private'
# я сделал это условия в самом хендлере 
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda msg: msg.text == 'Поддержать разработку', chat_types=["private"])
def support(message: types.Message):
    # mess2 = '''Треуг.(Тр.)➡️Треугольник\nКв.➡️Квадрат\nПрямоуг.➡️Прямоугольник(-ый)\nОкр.➡️Окружность(круг)\nВпис.➡️Вписанный\nОпис.➡️Описанный\nПрил.➡️Прилежащая\nРавноб.➡️Равнобедренный\nКат.➡️Катет\nГипот.➡️Гипотенуза\nСтор.➡️Стороны\nИзв.➡️Изввестный(-ая)\nH(h)➡️Высота в общей геометрии\nS(s)➡️Площадь в общей геометрии\nL➡️Сторона в общей геометрии\nM(m)➡️Медиана в общей геометрии\nПроизв.➡️Произвольный(ого)\nПолуп.➡️Полупериметр\nОсн.➡️Основние/основа\nЧ/з➡️Через\nР-но➡️Ровно\nРавтост.➡️Равносторонний'''
    # mess3 = 'Связь с разработчиком: @MarcoPopa'
    # mess4 = 'P.s после каждого ответа бота можете сразу продолжать искать другие формулы. Введи название формулы  ниже'
    # mess5 = 'Введи ниже переменную а'
    # mess6 = 'Введи переменную b'
    # mess7 = 'Введи переменную с'
    bot.send_message(
        chat_id=message.chat.id,
        text='Поддержите разработку если считаете это нужным, это поможет проэкту существовать и развиваться '
             'Карта ПриватБанка: 5168 7559 0884 1170 Спасибо заранее!')


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda msg: msg.text == 'Быстрый поиск:', chat_types=["private"])
def support(message: types.Message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
    # смысла создвать кнопки таким образом особого нет, рекомендую просто сделать так.
    # algebra = types.KeyboardButton()
    # geoma = types.KeyboardButton('Геометрия♾️')
    # nazadbistr = types.KeyboardButton('Вернуться в главное меню⬅️')
    markup.add('Алгебра', 'Геометрия♾️', 'Вернуться в главное меню⬅️')
    bot.send_message(
        chat_id=message.chat.id, 
        text='Выбери предмет:', 
        # parse_mode='html', 
        reply_markup=markup)
```

UPD1.
Попробуйте вот это

```
from telebot import TeleBot, types
import math
from pymongo import MongoClient

import config

bot = TeleBot(config.BOT_TOKEN)

# CONTENT_TYPES = ["text", "audio", "document", "photo", "sticker", "video", "video_note", "voice", "location", "contact",
#                  "new_chat_members", "left_chat_member", "new_chat_title", "new_chat_photo", "delete_chat_photo",
#                  "group_chat_created", "supergroup_chat_created", "channel_chat_created", "migrate_to_chat_id",
#                  "migrate_from_chat_id", "pinned_message"]

cur_state = None

cluster = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://palladium:rinigu77@cluster0.fzugi.mongodb.net/mathbot?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
db = cluster["mathbot"]
user = db["users"]


def Handler_SquareRoot(message: types.Message):
    global cur_state
    a, b, c = [int(num) for num in message.text.split(' ')]

    D = b * b - 4 * a * c
    if D < 0:
        mess = "Дискриминант меньше нуля, корней нет"
    elif D == 0:
        x = -b / (2 * a)
        mess = f"Дискриминант равен нулю, единственный корень:\nx = {x:.5f}"
    else:
        x1 = (-b + math.sqrt(D)) / (2 * a)
        x2 = (-b - math.sqrt(D)) / (2 * a)
        mess = f"Дискриминант больше нуля, корни:\nx1 = {x1:.5f}, x2 = {x2:.5f}"

    cur_state = None
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess)


# States
state_SquareRootGet = "SquareRootGet"
state_handlers = {
    state_SquareRootGet: Handler_SquareRoot
}

already_added = False


# Функция, обрабатывающая команду /start
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"], chat_types=['private'])
def start(message: types.Message):
    if user.find_one({"user_id": message.from_user.id}):
        return
    else:
        user.insert_one({"user_id": message.from_user.id, "user_name": f"{message.from_user.username}"})

    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
    markup.add('Начать поиск:', 'Связь с разработчиком', 'Поддержать разработку',
               'Список сокращений:', 'Быстрый поиск:', 'Калькулятор кв. уравнений')
    bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id,
                     text=f'Привет, {message.from_user.first_name}!\n'
                          f'Я формулознайка, наилучший бот - помощник в поиске формул по математике , '
                          f'выбери что ты хочешь:',
                     # parse_mode='html',
                     reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(commands=["checkuser"], func=lambda msg: msg.from_user.id == 1219000385)
def check_user(message: types.Message):
    users = user.find({})
    coutn_users = user.count_documents({})
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Кол-во пользователей, которые используют Ваш бот: {coutn_users}")
    for user_ in users:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"ID = {user_['user_id']}\nUsername = @{user_['user_name']}")


# во-первых делайте для каждого вашего if одтельный хендлер
# не и всякие content_types=["text"] который стоят по-умолчанию смысла писать нет
# также рекомендую указывть аннотации, они облегчат написание кода
# к примеру message: types.Message, если вы юзате pycharm
# то он будет давать подсказки если вы напишете message. (с точкой)
# вместо ваших ифов делаете такую конструкцию, вы будете смотреть на хендлер
# и сразу поймете что он делает и при каких условиях срабатывает
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda msg: msg.text == "Калькулятор кв. уравнений")
def func(message: types.Message):
    global cur_state
    # даже pycharm ругается на эту запись
    # if not cur_state is None:
    # делайте так. Так даже понятнее, типа такой-то стейт является не None
    if cur_state is not None:
        state_handlers[cur_state](message)
        print("Changed state to ", cur_state)
    else:
        # зачем вы создаете переменную mess? Оно же только мешает восприятию
        # mess = "Введи a, b, c из a*x*x + b*x + c = 0"
        # просто сделайте перенос строки
        bot.send_message(
            chat_id=message.chat.id,
            text="Введи a, b, c из a*x*x + b*x + c = 0",
            # зачем вам указывать parse_mode? Вы же не пользуетесь им.
            # parse_mode='html',
            reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())
        cur_state = state_SquareRootGet
        print("Changed state to ", cur_state)


# здесь у вас была просто функция без декоратора, потому бот не видел её
# я разбил её на два хендлера
# ах и ещё вместо ифа if message.chat.type == 'private'
# я сделал это условия в самом хендлере
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda msg: msg.text == 'Поддержать разработку', chat_types=["private"])
def support(message: types.Message):
    bot.send_message(
        chat_id=message.chat.id,
        text='Поддержите разработку если считаете это нужным, это поможет проэкту существовать и развиваться '
             'Карта ПриватБанка: 5168 7559 0884 1170 Спасибо заранее!')


@bot.message_handler(chat_types=['private'], func=lambda msg: msg.text == 'Быстрый поиск:')
def fast_search(message: types.Message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
    markup.add('Алгебра', 'Геометрия♾️', 'Вернуться в главное меню⬅️')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выбери предмет:', reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(chat_types=['private'], func=lambda msg: msg.text == 'Геометрия♾️')
def geometry(message: types.Message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
    markup.add('Квадрат', 'Прямоугольник⬜', 'Круг',
               'Треугольник', 'Ромб', 'Трапеция⏢', 'Вернуться в быстрый выбор⬅️')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выбери фигуру:', reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(chat_types=['private'], func=lambda msg: msg.text == 'Вернуться в быстрый выбор⬅️')
def back_to_fast_search(message: types.Message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
    markup.add('Алгебра', 'Геометрия♾️', 'Вернуться в главное меню⬅️')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     f'Ты в быстром поиске,{message.from_user.first_name}! Выбери что ты хочешь:',
                     reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(chat_types=['private'], func=lambda msg: msg.text == 'Алгебра')
def algebra(message: types.Message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
    markup.add('Вернуться назад⬅️', 'Таблица умножения', 'Квадратное уравнение', 'Графики')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     'Ты в разделе Алгебра, выбери что ты хочешь:',
                     reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(chat_types=['private'], func=lambda msg: msg.text == 'Вернуться назад⬅️')
def back(message: types.Message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
    markup.add('Алгебра', 'Геометрия♾️', 'Вернуться в главное меню⬅️')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     f'Ты в быстром поиске,{message.from_user.first_name}! Выбери что ты хочешь:',
                     reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(chat_types=['private'], func=lambda msg: msg.text == 'Вернуться в главное меню⬅️')
def back_to_main_menu(message: types.Message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
    markup.add('Начать поиск', 'Связь с разработчиком', 'Поддержать разработку',
               'Список сокращений', 'Быстрый поиск', 'Калькулятор кв. уравнений')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     f'Ты в главном меню,{message.from_user.first_name}! Выбери что ты хочешь:',
                     reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(chat_types=['private'], func=lambda msg: msg.text == 'Графики')
def graphic(message: types.Message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    markup.add('Линейная', 'Квадратическая', 'Степенная', 'Обратно-пропорциональная', 'Логарифмическая',
               'Функция в модуле', 'Другие функции(sin,cos)', 'Вернуться назад⬅️')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     f'Ты в поиске графиков,{message.from_user.first_name}! Выбери какой график тебе нужен:',
                     reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(chat_types=['private'], func=lambda msg: msg.text == 'Другие функции(sin,cos)')
def other_funcs(message: types.Message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    markup.add('sin', 'cos', 'tg', 'ctg', 'Вернуться назад⬅️')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     f'Ты в поиске графиков,{message.from_user.first_name}! Выбери какой график тебе нужен:',
                     reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(chat_types=['private'], func=lambda msg: msg.text == 'Список сокращений')
def list_abbreviations(message: types.Message):
    bot.send_message(
        message.chat.id,
        'Треуг.(Тр.)➡️Треугольник\nКв.➡️Квадрат\nПрямоуг.➡️Прямоугольник(-ый)\nОкр.➡️Окружность(круг)\n'
        'Впис.➡️Вписанный\nОпис.➡️Описанный\nПрил.➡️Прилежащая\nРавноб.➡️Равнобедренный\nКат.➡️Катет\n'
        'Гипот.➡️Гипотенуза\nСтор.➡️Стороны\nИзв.➡️Изввестный(-ая)\nH(h)➡️Высота в общей геометрии\n'
        'S(s)➡️Площадь в общей геометрии\nL➡️Сторона в общей геометрии\nM(m)➡️Медиана в общей геометрии\n'
        'Произв.➡️Произвольный(ого)\nПолуп.➡️Полупериметр\nОсн.➡️Основние/основа\nЧ/з➡️Через\nР-но➡️Ровно\n'
        'Равтост.➡️Равносторонний')


@bot.message_handler(chat_types=['private'], func=lambda msg: msg.text == 'Связь с разработчиком')
def contact(message: types.Message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Связь с разработчиком: @MarcoPopa')


@bot.message_handler(chat_types=['private'], func=lambda msg: msg.text == 'Начать поиск')
def start_search(message: types.Message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'P.s после каждого ответа бота можете сразу продолжать искать другие формулы. '
                                      'Введи название формулы  ниже')


@bot.message_handler(chat_types=['private'], func=lambda msg: msg.text in [
    'Таблица умножения', 'Табличка умножения', 'таблица умножения', 'табличка множения'])
def multiplication_table(message: types.Message):
    photo1 = open('png/3ebc0dfa867e344cf30d81409cfd7558.jpg', 'rb')
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo1)


@bot.message_handler(chat_types=['private'], func=lambda msg: msg.text in [
    'теорема пифагора', 'Теорема Пифагора', 'теорема Пифагора'])
def pythagoras_theorem(message: types.Message):
    photo1 = open('png/maxresdefault.jpg', 'rb')
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.infinity_polling(skip_pending=True)
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137853/discussion-on-answer-by-oleksandrigo-------).

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте токен на правильность, вдруг не от того бота указали токен

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot('5374997789:AAH_eMyDtaeB_N0xPure_DR574Cnl9VD-b8')
```

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос

Comment: без проблем, прошу прощения!

Comment: я поменял код,я слегка полазил и стал работать только калькулятор,остально попросту не реагирует(токен верный должен  быть)

Comment: приложите изменённый код

Comment: это он и естььь